# Symfony 3 functional test error (KERNEL_DIR or WebTestCase)

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I need help regarding this, documentation doesn't help.

I have `app/AppKernel.php`, I don't use a custom kernel, however the functional test does not run.

phpunit.xml.dist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.8/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="app/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app" />
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

The error:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/jorgee/Desktop/Proyectos/Nano/proyecto-nano/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --no-configuration /home/jorgee/Desktop/Proyectos/Nano/proyecto-nano/tests --teamcity
Testing started at 21:35 ...
PHPUnit 6.1.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


Either set KERNEL_DIR in your phpunit.xml according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#your-first-functional-test or override the WebTestCase::createKernel() method.
 /home/jorgee/Desktop/Proyectos/Nano/proyecto-nano/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:126
 /home/jorgee/Desktop/Proyectos/Nano/proyecto-nano/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:165
 /home/jorgee/Desktop/Proyectos/Nano/proyecto-nano/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php:146
 /home/jorgee/Desktop/Proyectos/Nano/proyecto-nano/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/WebTestCase.php:33
 /home/jorgee/Desktop/Proyectos/Nano/proyecto-nano/tests/AppBundle/Controller/Security/LoginControllerAcceptanceTest.php:19
```

Comment: where's your phpunit.xml.dist file located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run phpunit with `--no-configuration` which prevents phpunit from loading the configuration file.

Either load the file, or set the `KERNEL_DIR` as an environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, I'm running it through PHPStorm right click -> Run. I will check if I can configure it